# Data not being exposed to react component from meteor publish

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I'm not getting data flowing from my db into my component.

I'm using react and meteor (w/ mantra), using simpleSchema/collection2 on the server. As far as I can tell I've got my publish/subscribe setup properly.

I've built things out with the mantra cli. (Which by the way is awesome)
Heres's my setup:

**Component: (client/modules/components/sidebar_hubs.js)**

```
import React from 'react';
const renderIfData = ( hubs ) => {
if ( hubs && hubs.length > 0 ) {
     return hubs.map( ( hub ) => {
      return <li key={ hub._id }>{ hub.name }</li>;
    });
} else {
return <p>No hubs yet!</p>;
}
};

const SidebarHubs = ({hubs}) => (

 <div>
     <h1> Hubs </h1>
     {hubs.length}
     <ul> { renderIfData( hubs ) } </ul>
  </div>
);

export default SidebarHubs;
```

**Container (client/modules/containers/sidebar_hubs.js)**

```
import {useDeps, composeAll, composeWithTracker, compose} from 'mantra-core';
import SidebarHubs from '../components/sidebar_hubs.js';


export const composer = ({context}, onData) => {

 const {Meteor, Collections} = context();
 const subscription = Meteor.subscribe( 'hubs' );

 if ( subscription.ready() ) {
   const hubs = Collections.Hubs.find().fetch();
   onData( null, { hubs } );
 }

};

 export const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
   context: () => context
 });

export default composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composer),
  useDeps(depsMapper)
)(SidebarHubs);
```

**Publication:(server/publications/hubs.js)**

```
 import {Hubs} from '/lib/collections';
 import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
 import {check} from 'meteor/check';

 export default function () {
   Meteor.publish('hubs', function () {
     return Hubs.find();
   });
 }
```

What am I missing obvious here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the outcome? (Is the component rendered? Does it render with no data? Did you inspect the DDP subscription to figure out if data was pushed to the client? Do you have data in MiniMongo itself?)

Comment: Just posted the answer, it didn't realize I was importing my component directly and not my container for the component.

Answer (score 0):

This confusing to debug as nothing was breaking... And the component was being rendered, just without data.

Tossed a couple of console.logs around and it seemed like my container wasn't even being ran. As I figured it was something obvious ugh.... In my main_layout.js file.

From

```
import SidebarHubs from '../components/sidebar_hubs.js';
```

to:

```
import SidebarHubs from '../containers/sidebar_hubs.js';
```

Works like a charm now. Good debugging skills go a long way...